# WPF - How to add textboxes to a wrap panel dynamically when number of textboxes come from a datasource

Tags: wpf, xaml, dynamic

I need to add textboxes to a wrap panel but the number of textboxes come from a database. How can I do this in XAML binding instead of programmatically.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try something like below code:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding NumberOfTextBoxes}">

    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding SomeProperty}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

</ItemsControl>
```